# How to align user profile image and name + other info

Tags: html, css, image, profile

I have been able to create a section for profile pic and the name and location and some other info to the right of the image.  However, to adjust the image with the info, I had to go through extra steps to make it look acceptable, but coding wise its not accurate, since it might create cross browser issues.

What CSS can I use to create a user profile pic and name plus other info in a way stackoverflow does it, for e.g:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/441049/aaa

The top section of this is what I am looking for.  I am still in the process of learning.  Thanks.

This is the code:

```
#manpic {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    display:block;
} 

#manname {
    color: #D7D7D7;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top:-60px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Have any HTML and CSS you're working with that you can post to get critiqued?

Comment: #manpic {
margin-left:30px;
margin-top:20px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px;
display:block;
}
#manname {
color: #D7D7D7;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-top:-60px;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

Comment: @AAA: don't post it as a comment!

Comment: @eric new to the site, why not?

Comment: @AAA: just edit the original post in the future. That means that you don't have to post it as a comment to every answer, and makes it clearer. Also, if you indent it by four spaces, it color-codes it, as I edited your post to do above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your code, except the padding might be an issue, test it out.

I would use IEtester to check the page out in IE7 and IE8
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Test in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.
If you don't see anything in those browsers then I really wouldn't worry about the code.

If you are using floats, then make sure you have clears. With IE I have found that padding sucks and you should always use MARGIN to adjust spacing in most cases between divs.

Hope that help!

Chris

Comment: hey Chris,this is the code i am using:   #manpic { margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px; background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; display:block; } #manname { color: #D7D7D7; margin-left: 150px; margin-top:-60px; font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana; font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px;

Comment: wouldn't the dragging of the top margin by using a negative create problems...?

Comment: Yeah you wouldn't need -60px for the top margin unless were needing to resolve below or above that div that is affecting it.